# LibGdx Android Keyboard Autocomplete

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, libgdx

I'm currently building a small game for Android using LibGdx in Android Studio. In the game the player uses the on-screen keyboard to enter different letters one by one.

My problem is that the autocomplete is one (since I use it when I'm texting) and this forces the player to click the "suggestion box" after every typed letter to actually make sure that the keyboard press and character input is registered. Since the input in my game should be one letter at a time I don't want autocomplete to try to "guess"/create a word.

I'm using the InputProcessor class with the "keyTyped(char character)" function. If I turn of the auto complete in phone settings (manually before starting the game) the input is registered and the correct character is passed in.

**So, my question is if there is any way to turn off/toggle autocomplete programmatically?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is old but if you or anyone else is looking for a way to do this then I have a solution. I built a completely new method for Android soft keyboard input to tackle the issues involved with the current libgdx methods. I am surprised to read auto-complete was actually working for you, because on all my testing devices it does not, and this is one of the problems I have attempted to solve.

I have built a sample project for people to work with that allows for much more reliable input using the Android soft keyboard, this includes swype, auto-correct, dictionary, etc. What you may be interested in is I have also included some customisation for the keyboard, such as the ability to disable auto-complete and suggestions. You would simply customise your TextFieldStyle with;

```
    textFieldStyle.androidKeyboardAutoCorrect = false;
    textFieldStyle.androidKeyboardTextSuggestions = false;
```

As of posting, no one has used this sample project and I have only tested on a few devices, so it may be a little erroneous. I will carry on maintaining it when/if feedback is received.

You can find it on Github [here](https://github.com/calanti/libgdx-android-native-keyboard-input) (source and executable apk)

If you have any comments/feedback please refer to Github or the [badlogic forum topic](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=23051)

Hope this helps!